# "cake bake" returns "env: node: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I'm experienced with Ruby but new to PHP, getting CakePHP set up on my machine and I would love some help.

I've downloaded a version of Cake and placed it at `/Users/zack/Sites/cake`

From that directory, I've done `cd cake/console` and tried running `cake bake` but get the error **`env: node: No such file or directory`**

I've tried running `chmod 755 cake` to change permissions but that didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty strange issue :))

1) You've installed coffeescript and it comes with a `cake` command. It's in `/usr/bin` so if there's no *local* cake available then it will run;

2) CakePHP's `cake` command only works if you are in an `app` folder (so `cd myCakeApp` first);

3) coffeescript's `cake` is a NodeJS script. It tries running `node something`. The error you are getting is telling you it could not find NodeJS.

Try prepending ./, so ./cake bake. That will make sure it only tries to run the cake command inside the current path/folder.

Comment: So I re-installed Node, running `cake bake` in my `cake` directory now gives me `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:111
    throw new Error("Cakefile not found in " + (process.cwd()));
          ^
Error: Cakefile not found in /Users/zackshapiro/Sites/cake/cake/config`

Comment: But why would you need NodeJS and coffeescript? Now you made coffeescript's `cake` run, not CakePHP's `cake`. Do you understand that those are two totally different "applications" and you are running the wrong one? It's a naming collision. A coincidence.

Comment: I understand that now. Thanks :) You're right, node and coffeescript have nothing to do with cake. Sucks they're named the same things. Going into the app folder for `cake` and running `cake bake` is now giving me coffeescript related errors, so now I'm even more confused

Comment: Try prepending `./`, so `./cake bake`. That will make sure it only tries to run the `cake` command inside the current path/folder.